# Location of Emacs 29 in a Debian 12 system

Tags: debian, dpkg, aptitude

I have installed Emacs 28.2 in Debian 12.

I have also installed Emacs 29.1 from bookworm-backports.

```
~$ aptitude show emacs
Package: emacs                    
Version: 1:29.1+1-5~bpo12+1
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Priority: optional
Section: editors
Maintainer: Rob Browning <rlb@defaultvalue.org>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 52.2 k
Depends: emacs-gtk (>= 1:27.1) | emacs-pgtk (>= 1:27.1) | emacs-lucid (>= 1:27.1) | emacs-nox (>= 1:27.1)
Provided by: emacs-gtk (1:28.2+1-15), emacs-gtk (1:29.1+1-5~bpo12+1), emacs-lucid (1:28.2+1-15), emacs-lucid (1:29.1+1-5~bpo12+1),
             emacs-nox (1:28.2+1-15), emacs-nox (1:29.1+1-5~bpo12+1), emacs-pgtk (1:29.1+1-5~bpo12+1)
Description: GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
 GNU Emacs is the extensible self-documenting text editor. This is a metapackage that will always depend on the latest recommended
 Emacs variant (currently emacs-gtk).
Homepage: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/
Tags: devel::editor, role::dummy, role::metapackage, role::program, suite::emacs, suite::gnu, use::editing
```

I  wish to point my system to use Emacs 29.1.

I could remove the 28.2 package but I wish to experiment with both before deciding which one to use.

I have seen `update-alternatives` which allows us to use multiple versions of the same program.

How do I find out the location of Emacs 29.1 file so that I can use it with `update-alternatives` ?

Comment: Are you sure you have both? How did you install the 28.3 one? Are you sure the 29.1 hasn't already overwritten and replaced the 28.3?

Comment: Please see the output of `aptitude show emacs` above. It shows both versions are installed. I think I installed `28.2` by doing `sudo apt install emacs` in Debian 12 which I think maps to Emacs `28.2`.

Comment: No, it shows version `29.1+1-5~bpo12+1` installed, nothing else. You can't have multiple packages with the same name on a dpkg-based system. The other numbers you see are other packages that also provide an `emacs` command (I am guessing you're looking at the `Provided by` line), but there is no suggestion that any of those packages is installed.

Comment: When I do   ``` $ emacs --version ``` 
It says :  ```GNU Emacs 28.2```
Does that not imply that Emacs 28 is installed?

Comment: That does, yes, you're quite right. Looks like you have emacs-gtk installed. My bad, I hadn't realized it was a metapackage.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find out the location of Emacs 29.1 file so that I can use it with update-alternatives ?

It's going to be the same path as any other version of emacs. So, that won't work.

Word of warning: I've been using emacs with *a lot* of MELPA packages (until I stopped using emacs); these were really the reason for using emacs for me. Changing versions without cleaning all caches of compiled packages has regularly broken my emacs. Re-compiling all the packages regularly took relatively long. So, assuming you're asking about changing between very recent emacs versions because you're trying to use very advanced features: don't. The whole ecosystem is fragile enough as is.

Comment: Any advice for me ? How do people manage 2 versions of Emacs? Are you saying that the only way is to remove the Emacs 28 version?

Comment: yes, I do. People typically manage mutliple versions of emacs only when they're emacs developers and build their packages from source, or they simply run their emacs in a container (e.g. through `podman`), and in both cases make sure they don't share caches and only these portions of configuration files that are emacs-version-independent (not that many lisp packages would take great care to separate state/data/cache from configuration… it's a finicky ecosystem)

Comment: Ok I will remove Emacs 28 from my system. Query : How do I remove only Emacs 28 ? I am not 100% certain of that.

Comment: just install the emacs 29 package.

Comment: I have posted a follow up query on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758547/i-have-2-versions-of-emacs-installed-in-debian-how-do-i-remove-one-of-them since this query diverges from the original question.