# I have 2 versions of Emacs installed in Debian. How do I remove one of them?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

This is a (self-contained) follow-up query to this query:

[Location of Emacs 29 in a Debian 12 system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758480/location-of-emacs-29-in-a-debian-12-system?noredirect=1#comment1445491_758480)

I am on Debian 12.

First I installed the Emacs in Debian 12, which defaults to Emacs 28.2.

Then I did:

```
sudo apt install emacs/bookworm-backports
```

So now I have ***two*** versions of Emacs with the ***same*** package name.

I was reading [`man apt`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt.8.en.html), which says:

> `install`, `reinstall`, `remove`, `purge` ([`apt-get(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt-get.8.en.html))
>
> A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by following the package name
> with an equals (`=`) and the version of the package to select. 
> Alternatively the version from a
> specific release can be selected by following the package name with a forward slash (`/`) and
> codename (bullseye, bookworm, sid ...) or suite name (stable, testing, unstable).  This will also
> select versions from this release for dependencies of this package if needed to satisfy the
> request.

Does appending the package name with `=version`
also work for `apt remove`?

How do I remove the Emacs 28.2 or Emacs 29.1?

Comment: "Does appending the package name with = version also work for apt remove ?" Should be quite simple to test for yourself, no?

Comment: I can't afford to make a mistake with that. That is why I asked.

Comment: `apt remove ...` => `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`.  And it's not that difficult these days to set up a throwaway container anyway. (See also: the options `-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So now I have ***two*** versions of Emacs with the ***same*** package name.

As said before: no. You *really* don't.

You *upgraded* your `emacs` metapackage from 28 to 29. That's it.

As a matter of fact, that *should* be it, but sadly debian's emacs packaging is slightly broken: the `emacs` metapackage *should* depend on any underlying emacs provider (`emacs-gtk`, `emacs-lucid`, `emacs-nox`…) *of the same version*; sadly, both the backports as well as the normal bookworm package both just say "yeah, emacs-something >= 27.1 is enough". Well, so you can upgrade the emacs metapackage without upgrading the actual emacs binaries. One wonders.

So, in order to actually get emacs 29, you need to run

```
apt install emacs-{common,el,bin-common,pgtk}/bookworm-backports
```

(assuming the `pgtk` build is what you want, my guess is that this is the main reason to upgrade to 29, especially since none of the other backends play well with Wayland on "hi-DPI" (as in: typical modern developer laptop screen qualities next to an external monitor) screens).

This will definitely replace the currently installed emacs 28 with emacs 29. At no point can you have two different-version `emacs`en installed with debian's packaging (phew.)!

Comment: The bug described in https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/1193  ( which disappears in 29.1 )  is the reason I wish to upgrade.

Comment: I honestly do think then you probably still want the `pgtk` backend. If you used `nox`, `gtk` or `lucid` before, you can simply replace `pgtk` with that in the command I show above, if you prefer that.

Comment: I followed your apt incantation and now I have Emacs 29.1. Many thanks.

Comment: quick debian packaging [bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1053752)

Comment: Dear Marcus : many thanks once again and great job with the bug report.