# Getting 'emacs-common-non-dfsg' from Debian bookworm-backports

Tags: debian, emacs, documentation, backports

This in reference to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/758547/150047). Many thanks to user Marcus Müller for providing the silver bullet for getting Emacs 29 from Debian backports. I've done this already, and profited.

However, one thing remains: the Emacs 28 documentation still lingers. I'm assuming I need to do `sudo apt install emacs-common-non-dfsg/bookworm-backports`, but this gives me a "referred to by another package" message. Perhaps this is a mistake from the Debian side (the backport author simply forgot to include the package)? Hopefully I can get the ball rolling from any insight into this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct, [the package hasn’t been backported](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/emacs-non-dfsg). The best way to fix that is to file a wishlist bug asking for a backport (run `reportbug emacs-common-non-dfsg` and follow the prompts).